# Custom Cursor code comes with a black square in webkit. Am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cursor

I have the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #test-area {
        height: 200px;
        border: 3px dashed #CCCCCC;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 20px; 
        cursor: url(./blank.cur), none;
    }
    #mycursor {
        cursor: none;
        width: 97px;
        height: 137px;
        background: url("arrow.png") no-repeat left top;
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10000;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#test-area').mouseout(function(){
           $('#mycursor').hide();
           return false;
       });
       $('#test-area').mouseenter(function(){
           $('#mycursor').show();
           return false;
       });
        $('#test-area').mousemove(function(e){
            $('#mycursor').css('left', e.clientX - 20).css('top', e.clientY + 7);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The following code works in Firefox and Chrome (and internet explorer?). However Chrome **also** shows a black square, even though I hid the standard cursor by replacing it with an empty one. However, the .png file shows in both browsers.

How I can make this cross browser compatible for modern browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this instead in your CSS:

```
#test-area {
        ...
        cursor: none; /*for chrome, let me know if its not cross browser*/
    }
```

Comment: Hey roasted. This actually works but somehow I cant get this to work entirely. I wrapped the "test-area" div around my whole site but the arrow will only show "outside" of the main divs. When I hover over the main body the nothing. If I only knew how to make the cursor appear on all divs.